# Order by clause query in Spring MVC with MapSqlParameterSource

Tags: java, sql, spring, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to a SQL query in Spring MVC 4 with order by clause. But it does not work. I am using MapSQLParameterSource class to define sql parameters.

```
    MapSqlParameterSource params = new MapSqlParameterSource();
    params.addValue("lowerLimit", lowerLimit);
    params.addValue("upperLimit", upperLimit);
    params.addValue("filter", filter.trim()+"%");
    params.addValue("order", order);
    String sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_Subject WHERE subjectName LIKE :filter ORDER BY :order limit :lowerLimit, :upperLimit";
```

It does not work actually. does not order any columns. When I try to hard coded it works fine as aspect.

```
String sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_Subject WHERE subjectName LIKE :filter ORDER BY subjectId DESC limit :lowerLimit, :upperLimit";
```

How to I Order by clause query with MapSqlParameterSource.

Comment: ` String sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_Subject WHERE subjectName LIKE :filter ORDER BY "+order+" limit :lowerLimit, :upperLimit";` Use this instead of `addValue`

Comment: Is not it cause any SQL inject in future in this way ? Because I am permitting to put it  directly to my query?

Comment: Remove unwanted characters before adding to sql varieble.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in this line :

```
params.addValue("order", order);//consider this return col_name
```

This will be translate it to :

```
.. ORDER BY 'col_name' limit ..
            ^        ^
```

and this is a wrong syntax, logically after `ORDER BY` you have to pass a **column name** and **not a value**.

```
.. ORDER BY col_name limit ..
            ^^^^^^^^
```

---

Instead you have to pass it to the query directly but be carfull to pass the correct name, this can cause Syntax error or SQL Injection if you pass a wrong input

Comment: Agree,have met similar problem not long ago